# Remove extra formatting on a custom tab

Tags: android

I just want to ask on how I can remove extra lines appearing on my tabs. Well, the first tab doesn't have a line but when I navigate to the next tabs the line then appears but only on the left side and this troubles me a lot. Also this only happens in `ICS` as far as I can remember. Moreover, at first I use a gradient on this and this doesn't appear but after I use a black background the problem then appears. Well for better understanding here's a screenshot.

This is what it looks like at first:

[image: this is what it looks like at first]

and when I navigate on tabs the line appears:

[image: and when I navigate on tabs the line appears]

Well you can see the line on the left side. How can I remove it?

Oh by the way as you can see there are dividers (the thick lines to box the tabs) that is manually added as a background image only and I think that is not the issue here. Anyway, here's my code for further review.

```
private TabHost tabHost;
    Intent intent;

    public static String fname = "";
    public static String lname = "";
    public static String fid = "";
    public static String eadd = "";
    public static String gender = "";

    private void setupTabHost() {
        tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        TabWidget tabW = (TabWidget) findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);

        //tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);
        tabW.setStripEnabled(false);


        setupTab(new TextView(this), "tab1", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1tabicon), new Intent().setClass(this, tab1Activity.class).putExtra("fb_id", fid).putExtra("first_name", fname).putExtra("last_name", lname).putExtra("gender", gender));
        setupTab(new TextView(this), "tab2", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab2tabicon), new Intent().setClass(this, tab2Activity.class).putExtra("fb_id", fid).putExtra("first_name", fname).putExtra("last_name", lname).putExtra("gender", gender));
        setupTab(new TextView(this), "tab3", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab3tabicon), new Intent().setClass(this, tab3Activity.class).putExtra("fb_id", fid).putExtra("first_name", fname).putExtra("last_name", lname).putExtra("gender", gender));
        setupTab(new TextView(this), "tab4", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab4tabicon), new Intent().setClass(this, tab4Activity.class));
        //setupTab(new ImageView(this), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

        tabHost.setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        fname = getIntent().getStringExtra("fname");
        lname = getIntent().getStringExtra("lname");
        eadd = getIntent().getStringExtra("eadd");
        fid = getIntent().getStringExtra("fbid");
        gender = getIntent().getStringExtra("gender");

        setupTabHost();

    }

    private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag, Drawable drawable, final Intent i) {
        View tabview = createTabView(tabHost.getContext(), tag, drawable);
        TabSpec setContent = tabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(i);
        tabHost.addTab(setContent);
    }

    private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text, final Drawable icon) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
        tv.setText(text);

        ImageView bg_icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_bg);
        bg_icon.setImageDrawable(icon);
        return view;
    }
```

I need to remove it so badly since it irritates my eyes and I've wasted my day just looking for an answer ends up asking it here anyway. haha! Thanks in advance for those who can help.

Comment: Make sure your `rsvptabicon` isn´t different from the other tab icons you´re using. I´m pretty sure this line is related to your drawables

Comment: oh, your right man. found out some extra white lines on my png. but can't tell why this problem also happens in my other icons. oh well as long as its solved. you can put your comments to the answer so I can select it as the answer. sorry for missing that out cause I got really focused on the codes. thanks!

Comment: Ok, I´ll post my comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your rsvptabicon isn´t different from the other tab icons you´re using. I´m pretty sure this line is related to your drawables.